# gorm: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am trying to connect to my database created by the following docker configs using gorm:

```yaml
services:
  app:
    build: 
      context: .
      # Correct the path to your Dockerfile
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - db
  
  db:
    container_name: simple_api_db_user
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: mateen
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: simple_api_db_user
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5430:5430"
  
volumes:
  db_data:

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

here is the code to my postgres connection in golang:

```golang
func NewPostgresConnection() (*gorm.DB, error) {
    psqlConfig, err := dbConfigs.NewPostgresqlConfig()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlConfig.Dsn())
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("DB Connection error : ", err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }

    if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Println("DB Ping error: ", err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }

    gdb, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(psqlConfig.Dsn()), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = Migrate(gdb)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return gdb, nil
}
```

and here is my config DSN when I print it out:
`&{host=simple_api_db_user user=mateen password=password dbname=simple_api_db_user port=5430 sslmode=disable TimeZone=UTC}`

I am getting the following error when running my app:

```
simple-api-user-app-1  | 2023/05/10 14:05:16 DB Ping error:  dial tcp 172.31.0.2:5430: connect: connection refused
simple-api-user-app-1  | 2023/05/10 14:05:16 dial tcp 172.31.0.2:5430: connect: connection refused
```

Here is my Dockerfile even though I think it might be irrelevant:

```
# Builder
FROM golang:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

RUN go install github.com/cosmtrek/air@latest

COPY . .

CMD [ "air" ]

EXPOSE 8080
```

**PS:** When I try to connect to postgres port to 5430 in dbeaver, I get the following error:

```
The connection attempt failed.
  EOFException
  java.io.EOFException
```

Edit: the changed

Comment: `host=localhost`, this is incorrect. Try setting `host` to `simple_api_db_blog`.

Comment: you are right but may I ask why? @ZekeLu

Comment: In docker, the app and db run in different containers, meaning they have different IPs. This is the reason why you need to replace localhost with the docker service or container name of the db. The service or container name will be resolved to the correct IP of the db container.

Comment: @norym thanks for the details. can you check out the question now? the previous method mentioned by the other one who mentioned did not work in this case when I am trying to up this compose next to the previous one.

Comment: @norym It is the same issue but with different config and different outcomes. its like if i change the port from 5432 to 5430 it changes everything. I am thinking it has something to do with the psql instance I have already set up on 5432. This is considering that now I have used the network names as you and the other answerer instructed

Comment: The postgresql server running in the container still listens on the port `5432`. And since the db container and the app container are attached to the same network (`backend`), the  app container can access the db container by container name (as explained by @norym). The port of the connection string still should be `5432`. The port mapping `5430:5430` does not work because there is not app in the container listening on port `5430`. The correct mapping should be `5430:5432`.

Comment: `To expose a container’s internal port, an operator can start the container with the -P or -p flag. The exposed port is accessible on the host and the ports are available to any client that can reach the host.`. See the doc here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports

Comment: @ZekeLu well said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the postgres container is listening on 5432. so the `ports` options should be set to `5430:5432`. this maps port `5430` on your host machine to `5432` on the docker container.